# JavaScript scroll indicator is at 100% when the end of a certain element is reached?

Tags: javascript, css, events, scroll, dom-events

I want to create a JavaScript scroll indicator. I found a nice tutorial with a pure Javascript solution on W3Schools and I used that to create an indicator.

My current code is as follows:

```
// When the user scrolls the page, execute myFunction 
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

    function myFunction() {
      var winScroll = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
      var height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight;
      var scrolled = (winScroll / height) * 100;
      document.getElementById("ambitionTitleTopProgressbar").style.width = scrolled + "%";
    }
```

This works nicely and it goes really smooth. The only thing is that it is only complete when the user is below on the pages. So it takes the whole document or `body` as the 100%.

The indicator is for a blog page, and below the article are comments, some links to other articles and a footer. Therefore I don't want the indicator to be full when the user is completely below, but when the user has reached the end of a certain element.

The content of the article is in a `.amb-single-content` class. Above this content are one or more other elements. Those elements should also be counted in the content.

I think I should modify the var `height`, because that is set as the 100%. But I don't know how.

How should I modify the above code, so that the the indicator is full (the var `var scrolled = 100`) when the bottom of the `.amb-single-content` is reached?